# Scrapy - xpath return parent node with content based on regex match

Tags: regex, xpath, scrapy

Good day,

I'm trying to use Scrapy to get information of websites recurively.
Startpoint is a site that lists URL's. I get those URL's with Scrapy with the following code:
Step 1:

```
def parse(self, response):
    for href in response.css('.column a::attr(href)'):
        full_url = response.urljoin(href.extract())
        yield { 'url': full_url, }
```

Then for each URL, I'm going to look for specific URL's containing a keyword (I'm doing each step seperate now since I'm new to Scrapy. At the end I'd like to run it by one spider):
Step 2:

```
def parse(self, response):
    for href in response.xpath('//a[contains(translate(@href,"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ","abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"),"keyword")]/@href'):
        full_url = response.urljoin(href.extract())
        yield { 'url': full_url, }
```

So far so good, but then the last step:

Step 3:
I want to get specific information from the returned URL, if there's any. Now I run into trouble ;o) What I try to accomplice:

- search with regex the element of which the value/contents matches the regex: ([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].*[A-Z][A-Z]) >> this matches 1234AB and/or 1234 AB
- return the whole parent div (later, if possible, I'd like to return the upper two parents if there's no parent div, but that's for later).

So when you take the HTML code below, I'd like to return the contents of the parent div (). Note that I don't know the class, so I can't match on that.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Webpage</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 class="bookTitle">A very short ebook</h1>
        <p style="text-align:right">some text</p>
          <div class="contenttxt">
            <h1>Info</h1>
        <h4>header text</h4>

        <p>something<br />
        1234 AB</p>

        <p>somthing else</p>
      </div>
        <h2 class="chapter">Chapter One</h2>
        <p>This is a truly fascinating chapter.</p>

        <h2 class="chapter">Chapter Two</h2>
        <p>A worthy continuation of a fine tradition.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

The code I tried:

```
2016-05-31 18:59:32 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2016-05-31 18:59:32 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://localhost/test/test.html> (referer: None)
[s] Available Scrapy objects:
[s]   crawler    <scrapy.crawler.Crawler object at 0x7f6bc2be0e90>
[s]   item       {}
[s]   request    <GET http://localhost/test/test.html>
[s]   response   <200 http://localhost/test/test.html>
[s]   settings   <scrapy.settings.Settings object at 0x7f6bc2be0d10>
[s]   spider     <DefaultSpider 'default' at 0x7f6bc2643b90>
[s] Useful shortcuts:
[s]   shelp()           Shell help (print this help)
[s]   fetch(req_or_url) Fetch request (or URL) and update local objects
[s]   view(response)    View response in a browser
>>> response.xpath('//*').re('([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].*[A-Z][A-Z])')
[u'1234 AB', u'1234 AB', u'1234 AB', u'1234 AB']
```

First of all, it returns the match 4 times, so at least it can find something. I searched for 'scrapy xpath return parent node' but that only gave me a 'solution' for getting only one result:

```
>>> response.xpath('//*/../../../..').re('([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].*[A-Z][A-Z])')
[u'1234 AB']
```

I also tried something like:

```
>>> for nodes in response.xpath('//*').re('([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].*[A-Z][A-Z])'):
...     for i in nodes.xpath('ancestor:://*'):
...         print i
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 2, in <module>
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'xpath'
```

But that didn't help either.
Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction. First of all because I don't have a clue why the regex is matching 4 times, secondly because I've no ideas left of getting to where I want. Just reviewed most, promising, results that the 'Questions that may already have your answer' showed. But didn't find my solution in that. My best guess is that I have to build some sort of loop, however again, no clue. :s

At the end I try to get a which outputs the results containing the URL it found in step 1 and step 2, together with the data from step 3.

Thanks!
KR,
Onno.

Answer (score 0):

the `re` method extracts data after the xpath selectors extract the elements of interest, please check the [documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html?highlight=regular%20expressions#using-selectors-with-regular-expressions) for more information. If you know the element (maybe `div` in this case) you could iterate over all divs checking their content or use scrapy's built-in support for regular expressions inside XPath; using your previous example, something like this:

```
response.xpath('//div[re:test(., "[0-9]{4}\s?[A-Z]{2}")]').extract()
```

returns

```
[u'<div class="contenttxt">\n            <h1>Info</h1>\n        <h4>header text</h4>\n\n        <p>something<br>\n        1234 AB</p>\n\n        <p>somthing else</p>\n      </div>']
```